# I have a problem in my internet. I have a descent internet speed but still getting high ping

Tags: networking

```
C:\Windows\system32>tracert www.google.com

Tracing route to www.google.com [172.217.31.228]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  homerouter.cpe [192.168.8.1]
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14   174 ms    59 ms   278 ms  hkg07s28-in-f4.1e100.net [172.217.31.228]
```

I tried running tracert on my PC and this shows. It's very unusual since I can access google.com easily. Is there a way to fix this

Answer (score 0):

ICMP response functionality on hosts might be blocked due security reasons.
See here:
https://community.spiceworks.com/networking/articles/2531-traceroute-request-timed-out-why-traceroute-is-broken